# Wordpress Ajax 504 (Gateway Time-out)

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I tried 3 different form plugins on my website, all of them could send email after submit, but the Ajax will keep loading until 504 (Gateway time-out), like CF7 and WPForms, and Ninja Forms.

I modify setting in nginx and php-fpm already, nothing help this issue.

[CF7 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SQzP.jpg)

Comment: im getting 200 response https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9GXI.png

Comment: Finally I fix this issue by using smtp mailer instead of sendmail() installed in the server.